# List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

Tags: java

I understand `List` is an `interface` and `ArrayList` is just a `class`. I think I also understand the potential benefits of defining `numbers` with a less restrictive type than `ArrayList`.

That said, what's the **difference**, and pros/cons between:

1. `List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
2. `List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();`

?

Comment: Yes, sorry @A Paul - I looked quickly but didn't see that Q&A. I clearly should have searched better. Happy to close this one!

Comment: The diamond operator `<>` was added in Java 7. Before Java 7, option 1 was the only way to write it. As of Java 7, option 2 is a shorter way to write option1.